# Numerical method to solve the 1st-order 2D PDE equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I'm trying to find the numerical solution of the first-order partial differential equation (PDE) in two-dimensional space which is following:
$$
\frac {\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}+A(x,y)\frac {\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y} = B(x,y)
$$
where the boundary conditions are Dirichlet and periodic along y-direction:
$$
f(0,y) = c_1, f(L_x,y) = c_2, f(x,0) = f(x,L_y)
$$
and $ A(x,y) $ and $ B(x,y) $ are non-constant field values.

The outline of the calculation domain is:
[image: Governing equation and simulation domain]

During my research, I tough numerical schemes for hyperbolic PDEs could be useful (such as [MacCormack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacCormack_method) or [Lax-Wendroff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lax%E2%80%93Wendroff_method)), but those methods are marching through time.
I'm not sure how to guarantee the converged solution by just exchanging $\partial t$ to $\partial x$.

Therefore,

1. Is there a suitable numerical method to solve the above governing equation?
2. Is it okay to add an artificial time term (e.g. $ f_t + f_x + Af_y = B$) to utilize the MacCormack scheme until the $f_t $ vanishes?

Comment: Your problem is a first order scalar equation, for which the initial conditions are usually set along a curve on $(x,y)$ plane (plus some non-degeneracy conditions). What you are drawing (a square region) most probably leads to an ill posed problem. My first guess would be that your problem simply has no solution and hence it does not make much sense about solving it numerically.

Comment: @Artem Thanks for your deep insight into this problem. Maybe the ill-posed problem led me to get a diverged solution when I used a standard forward or backward finite difference gave. The above PDE equation was derived from governing equations so I believed that it is a physically possible problem. So, I'm hoping for a suitable numerical method to solve it. Thanks for your help.